# Add sorting functionality to dynamically created grid

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, pagination

I use knockout paged grid as seen in [this example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/grid.html). The [library](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/resources/knockout.simpleGrid.1.3.js) dynamically creates a grid table and I want to change it a bit for using sort function after click at the header's text.

Instead of

```html
<th data-bind="text: headerText "> </th>
```

I want to see this:

```html
<th>
    <a data-bind="click: MyPage.sort, text: headerText" ></a>
</th>
```

But it doesn't work. If I called  `click: console.log(MyPage.sort)` it writes "undefined", and after `click: console.log(MyPage.sort())`:

> ```
> Object function MyPage() {
>     // body of function
>     ...
>     self.sort = function(item, event) {
>         console.log('qwerty')
>         ...
>     }
>     ... } has no method 'sort'
> ```

Is there any way to call "sort" in this example? Or are there other ways (besides changing knockout.simpleGrid.1.3.js)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution ...

After binding - get the headers with jquery and just link the onclick events to the viewModel.

```
var headers = $('.ko-grid').find('th');
headers[0].onclick = function() { viewModel.sortByName(); };
headers[1].onclick = function() { viewModel.sortBySales(); };
headers[2].onclick = function() { viewModel.sortByPrice(); };
```

Working example ...

http://jsfiddle.net/2JxZA/1/